# Enqueuing scripts in footer does not working with WordPress 3.6

Tags: wordpress, scripting

I have a strange problem since I last updated WordPress to 3.6: My enqueuing method isn't able to place my scripts in the footer.

Here's my code (that worked good with WordPress 3.5 and previous versions):

```
function my_scripts_method() {

    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/waypoints.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);

    // My functions file
    wp_enqueue_script('theme_functions', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/functions.js', array('jquery', 'flexslider', 'waypoints'), null, true);
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts_method', 20 );
```

Anyone has an idea?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am not sure you could register your script then try the enqueue script

Comment: Any errors in your log file?  Are you sure it's not an error before (or earlier in) the `wp_footer()` call?  I assume you already have a `wp_footer()` call if it was working before

Answer (score 0):

You should have registered your jquery file after remove the default wordpress jquery.

Try this:

```
function load_external_jQuery() { // load external file  

    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
    wp_register_script('jquery', ("http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"), false);
    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');
    wp_register_script('flexslider', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/jquery.flexslider-min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('flexslider');
    wp_register_script('waypoints', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/waypoints.min.js', array('jquery'), null, true);
    wp_enqueue_script('waypoints');

    wp_enqueue_script('theme_functions', get_template_directory_uri().'/js/functions.js', array('jquery', 'flexslider', 'waypoints'), null, true);
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'load_external_jQuery');
```

Comment: For a complete list of registered files inspect `$GLOBALS['wp_scripts']` in the admin UI.